# Linq Conditions .ANY() issues

Tags: linq

I am trying to do condition by comparing between dates. My class variables are like this is like this

```
 public class SVCSpecialSchedule : BaseAuditEntity
 {
public virtual int ID { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual string Description { get; set; }
public virtual IList<SVCSpecialScheduleList> SpecialScheduleList { get; set; }
public virtual IList<SpecialScheduleAssignment> SpecialScheduleAssignment { get; set; }
}
```

Now my Linq Query is below .

```
return _session.QueryOver<SVCSpecialSchedule>().Where
                                (sg => (sg.LastModifiedTimeStamp >= startDate
                                           && sg.LastModifiedTimeStamp <= endDate)
                                       || (sg.SpecialScheduleList.Any(ssl => ssl.LastModifiedTimeStamp >= startDate
                                                                         && ssl.LastModifiedTimeStamp <= endDate)
                                       )
                                    .List();
```

Now i am facing an issue like below

> System.Exception
>     HResult=0x80131500
>     Message=Unrecognised method call: System.Linq.Enumerable:Boolean Any[SVCSpecialScheduleList](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ServicesDomainModel.BOS.MerchandiseManagement.SVCSpecial.SVCSpecialScheduleList], System.Func`2[ServicesDomainModel.BOS.MerchandiseManagement.SVCSpecial.SVCSpecialScheduleList,System.Boolean])
>     Source=NHibernate

Comment: Kindly help anyone please, i stuck with this

Comment: Are you using LINQ to Objects/SQL/EF 6/EF Core 2.0/EF Core 2.1/EF Core 3.x? PS Don't expect answers in minutes from a free forum.

Comment: I am using EF 6